# How to recover lost data in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hi guys I am just facing with big problem I was working on my computer and of course I was in the blender suddenly electricity switched off and it happened again then my project turned into default file it shows true size of my project below of the icon but when i open it shows default project how can i recover it please help i just need to recover my project

Comment: file>>recover autosave

Comment: No way all of them have been removed ((

Comment: Depends on how your file got lost. If it's due to a system crash during a Blender session, you could try to access the operating system's temp folder. On Windows, open the file explorer, then type %TMP% in the address bar. I was able to recover files from there at a few occasions, where Blender itself would tell me that there is nothing to recover.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called recover auto save, when you go to
File > Recover auto save

You should be able to get a file called something like 9036...or other 4 digit number as in my case. It also migth be called "quit". As long as you have not opened new projects it should be there.

It itself is a file in the temp folder