# How to get progress back after reloading file

Tags: animation, error, graph-editor

An entire section of my animation is missing and I think I might have deleted it by accident yesterday before saving it. Is there any way I can get it back? Kinda freaking out rn lol this animation took a long fking time to make

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139142/how-to-recover-lost-data-in-blender  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173916/does-blender-2-8-have-an-autosave-feature

Answer (score 0):

You can search in your save-folder whether you have files like this:

[image]

so they end with _autosave.blend. If the time/date + name fits, you can open them and if you are lucky, the autosave was at a time, when you work was pretty far.

2nd chance would be files which end with .blend1.

you can rename these files to .blend and then open them with Blender. This sometimes saved my life...